# Need an explanation of the changing value type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typescript-typings

I am using `@nestjs/config` and TypeScript in my NestJS project.

I'm trying try to access a boolean value with key "enabled" from `.env`. If you don't know what `@nestjs/config` is, in short, `this.configService.get(<key>)` reads value from `.env`.

**First try:**

```
const enabled = this.configService
      .get<boolean>("enabled");
console.log(`${typeof enabled}`);
```

The log shows `enabled` is of type `string`, so I understand the loaded value is always a string.

**Second try:**

Since the `typeof` tells me the value is always a `string`, I tried to `JSON.parse(...)` to get a boolean value:

```
const enabled = this.configService
      .get<boolean>("enabled");

console.log(`${typeof JSON.parse(enabled)}`);
```

But the compiler complains:

```
Argument of type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

`boolean | undefined`? Didn't the `typeof enabled` just tell me the type is `string`?

Probably the 2nd part is what the compiler is actually complaining about `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

**Third try:**

I tried the following code to avoid anything `undefined`:

```
const enabled = this.configService
      .get<boolean>("enabled") || '';

console.log(`${typeof JSON.parse(enabled)}`);
```

Now I got a new compiler error:

```
Argument of type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.`
```

This time the compiler changed its mind, thinking `this.configService.get<boolean>("enabled")` is returning a boolean, and since I added the `|| ''`, the return type is overall `string | boolean`.

**Last try:**

In order to make it all boolean, I replaced the `|| ''` to `|| true`, the code is like this:

```
const enabled = this.configService
      .get<boolean>("enabled") || true;

console.log(`${typeof enabled}`);
```

The log now shows me the `enabled` is of type `string`. Could someone please explain to me why TypeScript seems to be "changing" its mind when deciding the type of `enabled`?

How can I have a boolean value returned? If value is undefined return boolean `true`

I know NestJS's official documentation has this [Custom configuration file](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#custom-configuration-files) solving the same issue, but here I am mainly concerned about the TypeScript behaviour, so, please don't suggest that. I want to manipulate it without custom configuration file.

Comment: Your first two examples seem to be the same, although you say the output is different. I'd guess the default for the generic type argument is string and you didn't pass an explicit one at first, in which case everything else makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, that was my typo. I updated it. I would like to show clearly what I tried . When you say "everything else makes sense", it is to you. I hope someone help my question.  Are you some admin role? I see my comment even get deleted.

Comment: Possibly you're just confusing the _runtime behaviour_, in JavaScript (which is what `typeof` is showing), with the _compile time behaviour_, which is what TypeScript deals with. `.get<T>` is evidently typed as returning `T | undefined`, because the key might not be present, then when you do e.g. `|| ''` you change that to `T | string`. But the _actual value_ at runtime is a string. I don't know what you mean about "admin role".

Comment: I understand that & also guessed the same. But how to solve my problem? I need a boolean value be returned, if undefined return a boolean `true` like my last try mentioned.

Comment: Well if you know what's actually going to be returned if the key is defined is a string, why don't you use `.get<string>`? You claim `.get<boolean>` at compile time, but that's apparently not true (and, given you want to `JSON.parse` it, not what you _actually want_). If it was really a boolean, the typing would be fine: https://tsplay.dev/w2EQ8W.

Comment: I don't know why. That's why I post a question here.

Comment: Because my IDE complains & not runtime compalins, that's why I think it is a compiler error.  Because my IDE runs the typescript compiling.

Comment: The [examples in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#using-the-configservice) use `.get<string>` and it seems like it would be consistent with what you're seeing, maybe give it a try. Your IDE doesn't complain when you do something consistent with the types you've given it, `typeof` works with anything, only when _you say it's a boolean_ then treat it like a string. It's very important to remember that TypeScript and the type metadata **only exists at compile time** and is erased by compilation - it's up to you to keep that consistent with what's received at runtime.

Comment: Although you seem to have ruled out the custom configuration file, I'm not sure _why_; it looks like that _would_ let you use `.get<boolean>` because you could have e.g. `enabled: process.env.ENABLED === "true"` and then you'd actually get a boolean at runtime. Also I'd recommend in general not making assumptions about who voted and why they did so - there's discussion at e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/325416/248731 on why voting will continue to be anonymous.